# why do my modules keep getting rebuilt

Tags: apache-flex

I have a flex project, which has a main application, and then a number of small modules (17 of them).

For reasons I have not been able to figure out, when I do a 'debug-compile' to test, frequently (but not always), it decides to rebuild the modules, though, nothing within the modules has changed in any way.  Without the modules re-compiling, it takes about 5 seconds to build the app, but with it, it's upwards of 2 minutes.

I assume its that something the modules all need is getting changed, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: the only workaround I have at the moment, is to 'un-module' the modules...and then add them back in when I'm done, but thats obviously not a good workaround...

Comment: Are you using Flash Builder?  Is each module in a separate project?  If so, you can close the projects to prevent them from recompiling.

Comment: Yes, flash builder 4.  No, all in a single project.

Comment: so, here's a case in point.  I'm working on the contents of a PopUpManger window right now.  The only changes being made are to the internal, private mechanisms of this component.  None of the modules in question use this component.  Why, then, do they all want to recompile?  (I know theres a good answer...I'm just missing it :D )

Comment: I was under the impression that when a project compiles; it compiles everything in the project [that is used].  Even two minutes seems like a short compile time to me.  5 seconds sounds like a dream.

Comment: no...it doesn't, not every time....it would be easier to swallow if it didn't sometimes work the way I was asking...  /nose wrinkle/

Comment: I'm just kind of guesing; which is why I haven't posted a real answer. But, if Incremental Build is activated ( http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_20.html ) perhaps sometimes it uses it; and sometimes it rebuilds everything. I'm not quite sure how that feature works.

Comment: The default value of the incremental compiler option is true for the Flex Builder application compiler. For the mxmlc command-line compiler, the default is false.    .... I'm using the application compiler...so, I think you're probably right on there...but, how to tune it...its making bad decisions :D

Answer (score 0):

the FlashBuilder compiler I find has some terrible linking issues... I highly recommend looking at HFCD - HellFire Compiler Daemon.  It is an out-of-process multi-threaded mxml compiler that quite frankly just kicks some serious ass.  We saw our compile times drop astronomically for us, though our project is friggin huge.   Additionally since the compiling is not happening inside flash builder, flash builder is far more responsive now.

http://stopcoding.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/hfcd-pick-your-compiler-speed-how-about-10x/